# Can URL #anchor contain binary data?

Tags: json, url, binary, anchor

I'm trying to encode web pages state in #anchor. Right now I am base64 encoding a JSON string, but it sometimes gets too long (10K+). Apparently I hit some kind of URL length limitation and it just doesn't work right (it gets cut off and JSON data structure can't be reconstructed).

I talked with some of my buddies and they said try to bzip or gzip it. I tried that, but now my `#anchor` is binary data.

I haven't been able to decode it properly, and I'm not sure if it even got sent correctly as part of URL.

Does anyone know how to add binary data in `#anchor`, if it's a good idea, or how to come up with an alternative working solution for my problem?

Comment: What does that have to do with my problem? I'm trying to put state of webapp in #anchor so I can share the URL and reconstruct webapp state.

Comment: Hard to say. I don't know how to measure length of binary anchor string. :(

Comment: But what if it contains like `0` bytes? Those get cut off as far as I know. I know there are `0`s in binary string when I do gzip. I'll try jBinary. Thanks!

Comment: oooooooooooooh local storage!! that is the new fancy storage mechanism that i forgot about. yah let me try that man!!

Comment: so i will create `MD5(JSON_STRING)` as `#anchor`. Then store JSON STRING with key of MD5 in local storage. Then use #anchor to query local storage.

Comment: do you know if webapp needs any special permissions to use local storage?

Comment: nothing special. just check browser support, and i think there are libraries that help with that even. http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I know right, you got THAT right Mircosoft?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not bother with all of this.

Use `Local Storage` for your large data, and send a reference through your anchor to the data.

Comment: Good comment. I will accept this as answer if no other answers in next few day. :)